# if any different value between two tables(identical) then update with the new one

Tags: sql-server

i have **two identical tables**, lets call it tableA and tableB,
i set **tableA as source** and **tableB as destination**.
tableA and tableB have identical data,
but if there's any **new data on tableA on the same PK with tableB**, i want to automatically update the tableB according to the PK.

```
condition 1(identical data)> i just insert the data on tableA to tableB
           PK    Name  Age
tableA    D001  ANDY  17
tableB    D001  ANDY  17

condition 2(tableA!=tableB) 
i want it automatically update the column that different in tableB with the one in tableA
           PK      Name    Age     
tableA    D001  ANDY WEST  17
tableB    D001  ANDY       17
```

can anyone help me...

Comment: `Merge` will be help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Comment: Your question is vague, but I can suggest a simple `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, using a date column in `tableA` to decide which records are candidates for insertion into `tableB`.

Comment: please consider adding sample table data and the expected result in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Answer (score 0):

Is your query is like whenever data insertion happen in the tableA you want the same data to get inserted to table B. Then on insertion to tableA have a trigger to insert the same data to tableB. If you need update and delete changes also to get reflected then have trigger on update and delete also.